# How to have the same output size in my autoencoder?

Tags: keras, size, shapes, reshape, autoencoder

Good afternoon, I have a problem with my DNN model (a CNN autoencoder). I can't understand why the output shape isn't the same at the input shape, which parameters I wronged to write?

```
    input_img = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(3, 220, 440)) # adapt this if using `channels_first` image data format

x = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(16, (2, 2), activation='relu', padding='same', strides=1)(input_img)
x = tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2), padding='same')(x)
x = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(8, (2, 2), activation='relu', padding='same', strides=1)(x)
x = tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2), padding='same')(x)
x = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(8, (2, 2), activation='relu', padding='same', strides=1)(x)
encoded = tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2), padding='same', name='latent-dimension')(x)

# at this point the representation is (4, 4, 8) i.e. 128-dimensional

x = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(8, (2, 2), activation='relu', padding='same', strides=1)(encoded)
x = tf.keras.layers.UpSampling2D((2, 2))(x)
x = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(8, (2, 2), activation='relu', padding='same', strides=1)(x)
x = tf.keras.layers.UpSampling2D((2, 2))(x)
x = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(16, (2, 2), activation='relu', padding='same', strides=1)(x)
x = tf.keras.layers.UpSampling2D((2, 2))(x)
decoded = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(3, (2, 2), activation='sigmoid', padding='same', strides=1)(x)
```

The model finishes with output shape 3,224,440 :(